# Convert XLS to XSLX with Sharepoint and C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, excel-2007, excel-2003

I know about Word Automation Services, where I can start a `ConversionJob` which enable you to convert a .docx file to e.g. PDF or .doc.

I thought these services also allow the conversion of XLSX to XLS file - I was wrong. When looking at the `SaveFormat` [Enumaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.word.server.conversions.saveformat.aspx) it only supports Word. Excel Automation Services don't seem to have such a conversion job?

**How do I convert an XLS file to XLSX without using Excel automation (i.e. without having Excel installed on the server)?**

**EDIT:**
In the end I used [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) for the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) those libraries allow you to write excel files without using excel COM object.

You may read cell by cell and create a new worksheet copied from the other one (copy cell by cell)

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c might help you more

Comment: ExcelLibrary looks very interesting and is open source - but it doesn't convert, so I would still have to read the one file row by row and save that as XLSX... what a hassle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure that you can do it (converting XLS with is a row MS Excel file without having either Excel Services or MS Excel installed [Using InterOp] to XLSX which an OpenXML format)!!

If you want a way to convert it on a PC which MS Excel install check this link out http://devville.net/blog/2011/02/05/how-to-convert-rtf-document-to-doc-using-c/

But if found a way I would be happy if u share it to use.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the link you provided simply does an interop conversion of a MS Word file - I'm looking for Excel and **not** using interop.